# Commutation relation, field and conserved charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, commutator

One more question on basic commutation relation for fields. Let $\phi(x)$ be a scalar field and

$$
P^\alpha = \int d^3x T^{0\alpha},
$$

where $T^{\alpha\beta}$ is the energy momentum tensor. Now, suppose I calculate the spatial-like part

$$
[\phi(x),P^k] = \int d^3x'[\phi(x),\pi(x')\partial^k\phi(x')].
$$

Using the identity $[A,BC] = [A,B]C +B[A,C]$, why $[\phi(x),\partial^k\phi(x')] = 0$ ? (I would agree that it is zero without the partial derivate, but having $\partial^k$ confuses me a little bit.

Furthermore, why

$$
[\phi(x), \mathcal{H}] = 0,
$$

where $\mathcal{H}$ is the lagrangian density?

Comment: If $[A(x),B(y)]=0$ and if $\partial_x$ is spatial derivative, would you agree that $[\partial_xA(x),B(y)]=0$?

Comment: If you're not convinced on the point made by @Qmechanic, try substituting in the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @knzhou I don't understand your comment. You say something like $\partial_x (AB)$?

Comment: No, I mean the limit definition you learned in intro calculus.

Comment: @Qmechanic I guess your argument would hold for $[\phi(x), \mathcal{L}]=0$, with $\mathcal{L}$ the Lagrangian density?

Comment: It still confuses me that, e.g. $[\phi(x), \pi(x)\dot{\phi}(x) - \mathcal{L}] = 0$ would imply that $[\phi(x), \mathcal{H} ]=0$. I don't think this would always be the case, since the second commutator tells me that the field is conserved. Is this always true?